# Can we quickly determine the parity of some combinatorial formulas with special structures?

Tags: combinatorics

I've been thinking about this question for a long time.

1. Question

There is a triangular array with $N$ rows composed of 1s and -1s, similar to Pascal's triangle. The first row has independent probabilities of 1 and -1 each occurring with a 50% chance. Subsequent rows are formed such that each number is the product of the two numbers directly above it. Let the sum of all the numbers in this array be a random variable $X$. Find the kurtosis of $X$.

2.My thoughts

Consider the first row of random variables as $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{N}$.
$$X=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n-k+1} \prod_{i=1}^{k} X_{j+i-1}^{\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-1 \\
i-1
\end{array}\right)}$$
we can easily know that $E(X)=0$, Moreover
$$\operatorname{Kurt}[X]=E\left[\left(\frac{X-E[X]}{\sigma_{X}}\right)^{4}\right]$$
$$\sigma_{X}=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=E[X^2]$$
$$\operatorname{Kurt}[X]=\frac{E[x^4]}{(E[X^2])^2}$$
Based on the observation of the parity of the leading and trailing variables, we can find that in the polynomial$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n-k+1} \prod_{i=1}^{k} x_{j+i-1}^{\left(\begin{array}{c}k-1 \\ i\end{array}\right)}\right)^{2}$Upon expansion, terms with all even powers of variables can only come from the square of a single term.So:
$$E[X^2]=1+2+\ldots+N=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$
But it is so diffcuclt to do $E(X^4)$ like this.I have considered Lucas' Theorem:

$$
\binom{m}{n} \mod p = \binom{m_0}{n_0} \binom{m_1}{n_1} \binom{m_2}{n_2} \ldots \mod p
$$

where $ m = m_0 + m_1p + m_2p^2 + \ldots$  and $ n = n_0 + n_1p + n_2p^2 + \ldots  $are the base-(p) expansions of $ m $ and $ n$.

Specifically, $\binom{m}{n}$ is even if and only if, in the binary representations of $m$ and $n$, there exists a bit $ i $ such that $n$ has a '1' at that bit while$m $ has a '0'. This means that in the binary representation of $n$, there is a '1' at a position where $m$ has a '0'.

This can be more explicitly represented in binary form as $ m = m_0 2^0 + m_1 2^1 + m_2 2^2 + \ldots $ and $n = n_0 2^0 + n_1 2^1 + n_2 2^2 + \ldots$

$\binom{m}{n}$ is even if and only if there exists some $i$ such that $m_i = 0 $ and $ n_i = 1$.
What I know so far：
$$E[X^4]\ge \frac{N^2(N+1)^2}{2}-\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$
But the subsequent operations are still very challenging. Is there a better way to handle this?